# YII2 - Unable to access submodule's DefaultController action

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to figure this out how to access other actions inside the `DefaultController` of a module. I have this module structure.

```
 --module
   --website
     --module
       --hub
```

`hub`module is a `submodule` inside the `website` module, I can access this url `website/default/index` no problem there, the problem is this `website/hub/default/index` its not accessible.

but with this `website/hub/default` it all good, but i can't have that. Tried a new action `actionTest` its inaccessible also. Here the config i have

```
'urlManager' => [
   'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
   'showScriptName' => false,
   'enableStrictParsing' => true,
   'rules' => [
       // Default ruling for module/controller/action route to work
       '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
   ],
],
```

Answer (score 0):

I kinda solve my own problem with this, configuration

```
'urlManager' => [
   'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
   'showScriptName' => false,
   'enableStrictParsing' => true,
   'rules' => [
      // Default ruling for module/controller/action route to work
      '<module:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<controller>/<action>',
      '<module:\w+>/<submodule:\w+>/<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<module>/<submodule>/<controller>/<action>',
   ],
],
```

format should be `<module>/<submodule>/<controller>/<action>` I didn't know that `submodule` was a reserve word in Yii URL config, but i still have this issue.

When you create an action like `actionThisExample` the url should be like this `website/hub/default/this-example`, but it goes to 404 page. When i do it like this `actionThisexample` this url `website/hub/default/thisexample` works. but its not that good to have url s like that in my case.